# How can I use the classic Omit functionality applied to an array type instead of a type in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

How can I use the classic Omit functionality applied to an array type instead of a type?

For example, I've the following type

```
type Car = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: Record<string, unknown> | null
}

type Cars = Car[]
```

I would like to create similar types without `c: Record<string, unknown> | null`.

For example I could declare.

```
type Voiture = Omit<Car, 'c'>

type Voitures = Omit<Cars, 'c'>  // obviously not working
```

For code constraints, I ca't use `Omit<Car, 'c'>[]`.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [Indexed Access Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) for that to extract `Car` from `Car[]` then use [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) as usual and finally turn it back into an array.

```
type Car = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: Record<string, unknown> | null
}

type Cars = Car[];

type Voitures = Omit<Cars[number], "c">[]
//   ^? type Voitures = Omit<Car, "c">[]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigbwFBSnAXFAOwFcBbAIwgQBosoz8BnYBASwIHMbsBjfAJQjcA9ggAmAHiasOVKEQIBrAkIDuBAHxQAPoSIAbPRgC%20GDKEixEDFJYQBtALoBuU%20egA1IS2BEE0VADyJN7i8AgMdsTklA6yAETcceqOGAD0qdhQAHoA-EA)

Answer (score 1):

So in this instance I believe you would have to do the following:

```js
type Voitures = Omit<Cars[number], 'c'>[]
```

Where you are essentially doing

```js
type Voiture = Omit<Car, 'c'>

type Voitures = Voiture[]
```